# JS - Using 'this' and nextSibling - undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, html

So in my html, I am running a function onclick of a button. I then want to obtain the `innerHTML;` value of the sibling of the element that was clicked on however I am getting the old 'undefined is not an object error'. This is my html structure:

```
<button onclick="helloWorld();">
Click Me
</button>
<p>
Hello
</p>
```

And my javascript:

```
<script>
    function helloWorld() {
        var justClicked = this;
        var sibling = justClicked.nextSibling.textContent;
        alert(sibling);
    }
</script>
```

any ideas?

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.  You need to pass it from the handler attribute.

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: When you call a function like `foo()`, `this` refers to the global object or `undefined` (in strict mode).

Comment: Use event listeners (or event handler IDL attributes) instead of event handler content attributes and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **pass the `this` reference as parameter** into your event handler:

```js
function helloWorld(justClicked) {
  var sibling = justClicked.nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent;
  console.log(sibling);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="helloWorld(this);">
  Click Me
</button>
<p>
  Hello
</p>
```

Also note that the line break between the `<button>` and the `<p>` is counted as a sibling, so you will have to skip it.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem** is the meaning of the keyword `this` in the specific context.

You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value) that `this` is assigned to be the element clicked on IN THE INVOKED HANDLER. The problem is: the handler in your case is:

```
hellowWorld();
```

And that's all. Once you're inside the hellowWorld function `this` does not mean what you think it does (you can check and see it's actually the window).

You can **correct it** by passing the `this` reference like so:

```
<button onclick="helloWorld(this);">
```

and in the JS:

```
function helloWorld(elem) {
    var justClicked = elem;
    var sibling = justClicked.nextSibling.textContent;
    alert(sibling);
}
```

EDIT: Another (nicer) way is (as JefréN. said in the comment) to indicate the meaning of `this` by using javaScript's [Function.prototype.call() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) like so:

```
<button onclick="helloWorld.call(this);">
```

Comment: Why don't you change it to `helloWorld.call(this);`?

Comment: @SLaks yeah sorry - that was the idea. Just forgot to change that (important) bit. I edited it to what I meant now.

Comment: @JefréN. you're right - it's actually nicer the way you suggested. I'll add it to the answer as an option. Thanks

Comment: @et_l: Glad you find it to be an improvement.